# Download file from VSTS with lightweight client (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfvc

I code PowerShell, and save it to my VSTS account.
But when I code costumer specific Powershell script, I write them in my VS on my computer, then download them/the file from the customer server via web.

Is there any lightweight client or PowerShell script to download the latest version of a given file or folder from a private VSTS repository?
So I don't have to install anything on the customer server, and I can easily update the local file with a saved script.

It's a TFVC repository, not GIT repository if that makes a difference.

Comment: REST API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/items/get

Comment: @EdwardThomson Is it easier than Neno's tool? - Can't seam to find out how to get started. Should something be downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neno Loje has built a small tool that can download one or more files directly from TFVC. It needs a couple of Client Object Model files, which are taken from the new TFS Client Object Model nuget files.

You can find it here:

- https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/03/14/download-files-from-tfs-version-control-and-set-the-file-last-access-timestamp-to-the-file-s-last-check-in-time/

[image]

The [TFS 2015/2017 version will work against VSTS as well as pretty much any TFS server out there regardless of the version](http://dl.teamsystempro.com/TfsToolsSuite.zip).

Alternatively, you could use the [TFS Cross Platform Command Line](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere), as long as Java is available on the target server

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. (Though it's a hell of a lot dll files :) )

Comment: I think you can prune significantly, but that's the complete set from the NuGet package.